# How to get money out of a smart contract

Tags: internal-transactions

I need some help unterstanding how to communicate with a smart contract.
Here is my story:

1. I gambled 0.2 eth on [idice.io](https://idice.io)
2. I actually won another 0.2 eth. They said they will return the amount ASAP.

Here is the contract:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3105b9a5d922e4aa855a11f31b5bebb2cf7d90a6e092f3f92a2c49dfffcf6a20

3. But now I have 0.4 eth stuck in some internal transaction

Will this money every arrive? Or is this some sort of scam?

In Mist I found a function like this:
[image]

But it doesn't work. Can you guys help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Ether is not stuck. It has been sent to you (if `0x633255..` is your address) in that internal transaction. Check your account and it should be 0.4 higher.